# Ошибка сборки проекта с ассемблерными исходниками

Tags: ассемблер, c++, visual-c++

Написал файл .asm, добавил к проекту Visual C++ 6.0, указал путь к ML. Ну, в общем как вроде и надо. В .asm есть функция, аргумент которой - массив, точнее, ссылка на него, а вычисляется число, и далее оно возвращается в C++ и выводится на консоль.

Компиляция проходит без ошибок:

> `Compiling...`
> `Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)`
> `1.cpp`
>
> `1.obj - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)`

А вот при линковке пишет:

> `Linking...`
> `Performing Custom Build Step on .\Debug\L5_1.exe`
> `“бва®©бвў® ­Ґ Ј®в®ў®.`
> `Error executing c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.`
>
> `L5_1.exe - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)`

хотя при передаче функции в asm просто числа, а не ссылки, всё нормально работает.

Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

**Добавлено.**

В Custom Build Step написано:

> `Commands`
> `C:\Masm615\ML /с  /Сх  /coff  $(InputPath)`
> `outputs`
> `2.obj`

Comment: Не очень понятно, как связана линковка и выполнение =3 Посмотрите, что у вас прописано в Custom Build Step - там какая-то бяка, судя по всему...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cпасибо за ответы! Естественно нужно писать

```
extern "C" int asmfuncname (int mas);
```

если в asm функция описана. Проблема была вот в чем: надо было указать, что ML имеет расширение .exe:

> `C:\Masm615\ML.EXE /с /Сх /coff $(InputPath)`

хотя если из cmd вызываешь, .exe указывать не обязательно...

Answer (score 0):

Не видя кода функции и вызова, а также не зная кода ошибки, можно только гадать. Поэтому на уровне догадки: сборщик не находит функции нужного прототипа в случае, когда передается ссылка.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему ML выдает некую ошибку (ему не нравится ссылка по какой-то причине). А среда от этого переклинивается. Я бы попробовал вручную прогнать компиляцию-сборку.
Также я бы обратил внимание на то, что C++ портит названия функций (декорирование). Соответственно, чтобы подключить asm'овый модуль возможно придется вписать в CPPшный файл нечто вроде:

```
extern "C" int asmfuncname (int mas);
```